# array, string, pointer manipulation in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, runtime

Supposedly there is a bug in this code, but it runs fine and with an output that I expect ("hello world").  Is there a problem with `return str`?

```
#include <string.h>

char* example(){
    // your code goes here
    char str[12];
    strncpy(str, "hello world", 11);
    str[11] = 0;
    printf("%s\n",str);
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char * check = example();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Success time: 0 memory: 2248 signal:0
hello world
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `null byte '\0'`? In any case, you don't have to manually set the null byte with strncpy.

Comment: strncpy you do @C.B. it will stop when it copes n characters and may not set the null terminator.  In this case it definitely doesn't.

Comment: @KeithNicholas only if source is longer than num bytes to copy, right?

Comment: @C.B, right, like he has.  11 is the number of characters, so he misses copying the 0

Comment: @KeithNicholas right, my mistake

Comment: The code now null terminates the string; it may or may not always have done so.  However, using `strncpy()` followed by an assignment is a bit clumsy, especially with the repeated 11s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Big problem!

```
   return str;
```

`str` is a local variable.  You must not pass its address to the caller because the contents of what it's pointing to are not guaranteed to be what you assigned to it in `example`.  This wouldn't be a problem if you defined `str` to be `static`:

```
static char str[12];
```

**Edit 1**

You can also `malloc` memory for `str`:

```
char *str = malloc(12);
```

If you choose this method, you must remember to `free` the dynamically allocated memory to prevent a memory leak.

Another method is to make `str` global:

```
char str[12];

char *example(void)
{
    ...
}
```

It is generally best to keep the scope of variables as limited as possible, however.

**Edit 2**

Still another method is to have the caller allocate memory for the string.  The following is an example:

```
void example(char *str, size_t length)
{
    strncpy(str, "hello world", length);
    str[length - 1] = '\0'; // Guarantee string '\0' terminated
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[12];
    example(str, sizeof(str));
    printf("%s\n", str);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The problem with this method is that, generally, the caller does not know the length of the string to be returned.

Comment: correct, but not sure I'd recommend static though.

Comment: @KeithNicholas Would you recommend `malloc`ing it or making it global?

Comment: I'd not reccomend global, as its basically the same as static, I'd either pass in a char* which then gets populated, and makes allocation a problem seperate from the function, or return a malloc'd char*

Comment: Making it static means that you can only usefully call the function once; thereafter, any other calls will share the return value.  Here, the string returned is constant, so it won't matter much, but most function return varying values.  For that, and for thread-safety, a static variable is undesirable.  It is often best to have the calling code provide the space (the best design usually takes a pointer and the maximum length).  Making the function use `malloc()` also works but places the onus on the calling code to release the allocated memory (but `strdup()` does precisely that.

Comment: Usually the function producing a string knows how long the result is, whereas the caller doesn't, so it's better to return malloced memory rather than have the caller provide it. In either case, the caller is responsible for releasing the memory, so that's not an issue. Note that malloc itself requires the caller to free the result at some point ... there's no reason why your own functions can't have the same requirement. Also, strncpy is error-prone and generally sucks -- it not only doesn't NUL-terminate, but NUL-fills the buffer, which can be inefficient. Best to avoid it.

Comment: `strncpy` is nearly always a bad idea; `strcpy` or `sprintf` or `snprintf` are better because they null-terminate their output.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is that the `example()` function returns a pointer to the local array `str`. When a function returns, all its local variables are no longer valid, and using pointers to them is undefined behavior.

It's apparently working because the `main()` function never actually does anything with the returned pointer. If you put

```
printf("%s", check);
```

in `main()` you would probably get garbage output there.